# 3D drawing with user interactivity

Tags: javascript, web

I'm looking for a javascript framework that allows user interactivity such as recoloring individual elements of a already drawn 3d model, and lots more.

I've been looking at three.js, but at first glance it doesn't seem to facilitate the user-activity I'm looking for.

Im just looking for advices, if any1 have any good references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js allows you to do this.  You're in total control of how you render your scene.  You have to write the code to tell three.js to alter the properties of your scene, but it is possible.

Here's an experiment I did 3 years ago with three.js:  [link](http://www.ianl.net/ianlb/new2.html)